# Modal window disappearing on Electron

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, electron

I'm testing out the electron way of building apps, and I'm currently stuck on a problem:

I want to show a modal dialog, but once it's finished rendering it disappears. It works fine in a regular browser, but not in the electron (chromium) window.

The modal is the bootstrap one found on W3schools:

```
<!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

And the method calling it is:

```
$("#myButton").on("click", function(){
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

The above method is called from a render process atm, but the same behaviour is seen when calling it from main! What am I overlooking?

Comment: I can't get this modal to appear in my Bootstrap web app using Electron.  It does not appear at all and the debugger complains about needing bootstrap-dailog.js.  After installing bootstrap-dailog.js it now complaining about *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined at bootstrap-dialog.js:41*

Comment: @tale852150 are you loading bootstrap-dialog BEFORE bootstrap? bootstrap-dialog assumes bootstrap is already loaded. NB: This has nothing to do with my problems tho! :P

Comment: I'm loading bootstrap-dialog after bootstrap has been loaded.

Comment: Hard to tell without any code! You should create a separate question so others can help you out! :)

Comment: Will do ... thx

Answer (score 0):

Just to locate the issue, I decided to rewrite the entire app. It's now rewritten as a single-page application instead. And yes, the modal window works as intended. My suggestion is that it was previously called from wrong process, and therefore disappeared as soon as it was rendered.

I wont accept my own answer, since it's obviously not a solution to my problem, but maybe it can help anyone else locating their problem! ;)

Comment: Hi, For me, My modal is not showing up and for that, do I need to install any other modal plugin to make it work?

Comment: @SiddaramH - see my comment above in OP.  Try installing bootstrap-dailog.js

Comment: Do you have the SPA code that you can add to this question?  It may be helpful to others.

Comment: @tale852150 as mentioned in first post I was working with the example from W3schools. The change I did was to move the code into my index.html instead of separate files. This way I managed to avoid the modal issue, but I've not figured out 100% why that worked. And now it's way too long since I worked on that project! :P